# The right way to migrate a code using Win32 API functions ReadFile and WriteFile to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, io, stream, fstream

I have a custom stream implementation that uses Win32 API functions like `::CreateFile2`, `::ReadFile`, `::WriteFile`. Also the stream implements `Flush` and `Truncate` functions that are not supported by `std::fstream` (its `flush()` flushes its internal buffer, but not the operating system buffer):

```
class WinStream : public IoStream
{
public:

    size_t Read(uint8_t* buffer, size_t count) override
    {
        const DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead = static_cast<DWORD>(count);
        assert(nNumberOfBytesToRead == count);
        DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;

        Check(::ReadFile(m_hFile, buffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, &NumberOfBytesRead, NULL) != FALSE);

        return NumberOfBytesRead;
    }

    void Write(const uint8_t* buffer, size_t count) override
    {
        const DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite = static_cast<DWORD>(count);
        assert(nNumberOfBytesToWrite == count);
        DWORD NumberOfBytesWritten = 0;

        if (::WriteFile(m_hFile, buffer, nNumberOfBytesToWrite, &NumberOfBytesWritten, NULL) == FALSE)
        {
            throw IoError(format()
                << _T("::WriteFile failed. This may indicate that the disk is full. Win32 Error: ")
                << ::GetLastError());
        }

        if (nNumberOfBytesToWrite != NumberOfBytesWritten)
        {
            throw IoError(format() << _T("Requested ") << nNumberOfBytesToWrite
                << _T(" bytes, but actually written ") << NumberOfBytesWritten << _T("."));
        }

    bool End() override
    {
        return GetFileSizeHelper() == GetFilePointerHelper();
    }

    void Seek(std::size_t pos, bool begin = true) override
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER li;

        li.QuadPart = pos;

        Check(::SetFilePointerEx(m_hFile, li, NULL, begin ? FILE_BEGIN : FILE_END) != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER);
    }

    void Move(std::ptrdiff_t offset) override
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER li;

        li.QuadPart = offset;

        Check(::SetFilePointerEx(m_hFile, li, NULL, FILE_CURRENT) != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER);
    }

    void Flush() override
    {
        Check(::FlushFileBuffers(m_hFile) != FALSE);
    }

    void Truncate() override
    {
        Check(::SetEndOfFile(m_hFile) != FALSE);
    }

private:

    void Check(bool success)
    {
        if (!success)
        {
            throw Win32Exception();
        }
    }
    
    LONGLONG GetFileSizeHelper()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER li;

        li.QuadPart = 0;

        Check(::GetFileSizeEx(m_hFile, &li) != FALSE);

        return li.QuadPart;
    }

    LONGLONG GetFilePointerHelper()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER liOfs = { 0 };
        LARGE_INTEGER liNew = { 0 };

        Check(::SetFilePointerEx(m_hFile, liOfs, &liNew, FILE_CURRENT) != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER);

        return liNew.QuadPart;
    }

    FileHandle m_hFile;
}

inline UniqueFileHandle CreateUniqueFile(const String& file_name)
{
    HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile2(
        file_name.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, //FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        NULL //&extendedParams
    );

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dw_err = ::GetLastError();

        throw IoError(format() << _T("Cannot open file ')" << file_name << "' for updating, error = " << dw_err));
    }

    return hFile;
}
```

What is the right (or modern) way to migrate this code to Linux? And what about Android, MacOS and iOS?

It should use non-buffered read/write functions.

Comment: Since you want unbuffered operations and already have a dedicated class that can take care of the lifecycle, you can simply use the POSIX file descriptors directly with ```open```, ```write```, ```read```, ```fsync``` etc. Those are supported on all Unix-like systems like Android and iOS. If you ever want buffered I/O, using the good old ```FILE``` works well since it comes with a thread-safe buffer and gives you access to the raw file descriptor via ```fileno(FILE*)```

Answer (score 0):

As Homer512 said, you should use the POSIX file functions, like `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`, and `fread`. You can find a reference for these functions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).

My personal preference for having the code work on many systems is using preprocessor directives, and having code for each os. A full list of os directives can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/).

To separate the code for operating systems, you can do something like this:

```
#ifdef   _WIN32
    //Windows code here
#elifdef __APPLE__
    //MacOS code here
#elifdef __linux__
    //Linux code here
#endif
```

You can then use a specific set of functions, like open a file, write to a file, then define them on different systems using their specific ways. You can also easily extend this to other operating systems easily.

Comment: There is no `open`, `read` and `write` on https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io page, they are POSIX functions but not standard C++ functions.